# Error return Haskell

Tags: haskell

i have some troubles here with this.

I'm trying to do something like that:

```
Prelude> func ["abacate", "aba", "baaba"]
["cate", "", "ba"]
```

this exercise, must return words without the substring `aba`.

```
elimLetras :: String -> String
elimLetras [] = []
elimLetras (x:y:z:xs)
    | elem x "aA" || elem y "bB" || elem z "aA" = elimLetras xs
    | otherwise = x : elimLetras (x:xs)
    | otherwise = y : elimLetras (y:xs)
    | otherwise = z : elimLetras (z:xs)
elimLetras (x:xs) = x:xs
```

this code it's not working right.

On ghci, i'ts return:

```
prelude> elimLetras "abacate" 
output: "cce"
```

Any tips?

Comment: If it isn't working, tell us how it isn't working. "it's not working right" doesn't help us help you.

Comment: I'm going to guess from the example and the code you've written so far that you want to remove the substring `aba` (and not `abc` as you wrote) in a case insensitive way. Is that right?

Comment: Yes sorry, i'm gonna edit this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you are trying to remove the case insensitive substring `aba` from a `String`. Your method of checking for a substring isn't bad. It wouldn't scale very well but you can keep it like this if you want. The main issue is with the multiple `otherwise` statements. You should only ever have one `otherwise` statement, as only the first one will ever be reached.

Here is a rewrite of your function with a couple of helper function:

```
import           Data.Char (toLower)

elimLetras :: String -> String
elimLetras (x:y:z:xs)
  | stringEquals "aba" [x,y,z] = elimLetras xs
  | otherwise                  = x : elimLetras (y:z:xs)
elimLetras xs = xs -- anything that has fewer than 3 letters is returned "as is".

-- Check if two strings are the same (case insensitive)
stringEquals :: String -> String -> Bool
stringEquals a b = stringToLower a == stringToLower b

stringToLower :: String -> String
stringToLower []     = []
stringToLower (x:xs) = toLower x : stringToLower xs
```

If you know about the `map` function, here is how I would probably write it:

```
elimLetras' :: String -> String
elimLetras' (x:y:z:xs)
  | "aba" == map toLower [x,y,z] = elimLetras' xs
  | otherwise                    = x : elimLetras' (y:z:xs)
elimLetras' xs = xs
```

Comment: one more question please. If i want to put this words on a array like this: 

prelude> elimLetras ["abacate", "aba", "baaaba"] 

What i should do?

Comment: That's where the `map` function comes in handy. You should learn about it if you've never come across it before. It is a higher-order function, you can learn about it more [here](http://learnyouahaskell.com/higher-order-functions). It's a way to apply a function to every element in a list.

Comment: Thanks Henry! I did like this:

prelude> map elimLetras ["abacate", "aba", "baab"] 

and it's works!